# Modify snowflake database by fill in value from Alteryx

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, alteryx

There are some records that are missing values.  I would like to modify/fill-in data into snowflake from Alteryx.  I would like to modify many records at once.

What is the best way to modify snowflake database from Alteryx:

1. deleting specific rows and append modified data?
2. modifying data using sql statement in Alteryx output tool?
3. clone original table --> create modified table --> replace table?
4. any other ways?

Sincerely,

knozawa

Answer (score 1):

Use an UPDATE statement in Snowflake.  There is no benefit to the other methods that you've suggested.  When you run an UPDATE in Snowflake, it is recreating the micro-partitions that those records are contained in regardless.  Your other methods would be doing that same operation, but more than once.  Stick with UPDATE.